# combine .htaccess redirect with apache alias

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In my host config I have apache alias:

```
Alias /jobs /var/www/my/web
```

pointing to root of cms (in other directory than main website)

Now I need to add redirect to point

http://mydomain/jobs -> http://mydomain/jobs/jobs

maintaining the url http://mydomain/jobs

I am not sure alias is necessary/posssible to achieve this effect.

UPDATE
As it is Drupal cms it also has its own rules like:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule inside `/var/www/my/web/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /jobs/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!jobs/).*$ jobs/$0 [L,NC]
```

Comment: unfortunately this has no effect.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: Without conditions I'm getting Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Comment: ok now you've update CMS part which was missing earlier. Many CMS like WP doesn't like internal rewrites. Does `http://mydomain/jobs/jobs` work without these rules?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166118/discussion-between-greg606-and-anubhava).